# Is it ok to use implicits to overload methods?

Tags: scala, implicit, overloading

In the following example, Human and Hero both walk the same way, but they run differently.

My goal is to have one signature for the method describe, but for run I want it to behave differently depending on the type parameter and in Walk, I want it to behave the same way all the time.

```scala
trait H
trait Hero extends H
trait Human extends H

trait Move[A <: H] {
  def describe(x: A): Unit
}

class Run[A <: H] extends Move[Hero] {
  def fooWithImplicit[A](x: A)(implicit hRun: A => Unit): Unit = hRun(x)
  def describe(x: A): Unit = fooWithImplicit(x)
}

object Run {
  implicit val heroRun: Hero => Unit = hero => println("I run like a hero")
  implicit val humanRun: Human => Unit = human => println("I run like a human")

}

class Walk[A <: H] extends Move[_] {
  def describe(x: A): Unit = println("we move the same way when we walk")
}
```

When I try to run this, fooWithImplicit(x) is still requiring the implicit to be passed, although I thought it will be just available in the Run context because it's defined in the companion object.

Comment: I don't get what is your use case intention here, can you elaborate it a bit please?
Second, the reason why your first snippet does not work, is because there is an already implicit in scope of type `Int => Int` called `$conforms` that comes from **Predef**. Third, your second snippet is not even syntactically correct. Anyways, I believe this is an [_XY_ problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), that is why I asking for clarification, we may help you if we understand your problem better.

Comment: It is still not clear why do you need an `implicit` if you use it in the single place in the local environment you fully control? Why you don't want pass that value explicitly? It is actually less of typing. Your third example doesn't clarify that at all. It really would help is you described your problem in words rather than just in code.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I hope this is clearer now. I also changed the example to not use Int => Int implicit.